# Spring Cloud Config in web application

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config

I have legacy Java web application (with Spring MVC and web.xml) which are deployed in Tomcat. I want to swtich configuration to Spring Cloud Config.

Structure of this application (just simplify it for example) - jar file with Spring Controller and services, which I want to do Spring Cloud Config compatible. And another module with web.xml, which add jar as dependency.

I added bootstrap.yml with application name to module, which packaged to jar in "resources" folder and add "EnableAutoConfiguration" and "SpringBootApplication" annotations, but got exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'foo' in string value "${foo}"
at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.parseStringValue(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:174)
at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.replacePlaceholders(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:126)
at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractPropertyResolver.doResolvePlaceholders(AbstractPropertyResolver.java:219)
at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractPropertyResolver.resolveRequiredPlaceholders(AbstractPropertyResolver.java:193)
```

Config server is run. I wrote simple client, which I run via main method and it  works, but when I deploy legacy app in Tomcat - it doesn't work.

Can someone help with it?

Comment: how do you scan properties ?

Comment: What do you mean? I'm using standard GIT-way in Spring Cloud and try to load properties from my GIT repository via Config Server.

Comment: Can we see some code. class where you are reading the value. Your properties file which has the config-server info. Also check if you have the dependency jars that you need. by looking at the exception all i know is you do not have that property in the file.

Comment: Is the config server accessible from the tomcat?